# php require seems to not include css files

Tags: php, css, header, include, require

I'm working on a project where I am learning the importance of having a header file with a nav and including that header file in other files so that my nav will display the same in all other vies.

The problem I'm having is the css that I linked to my header file is not being applied to a certain page... I think it has to do with file paths but I'm not sure. Can someone take a look at what I have and give me some insight? Thanks!

[css not being included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDENq.png)

[my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95wNh.png)

Here is my header file:

```
<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = 'login_system/';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <script scr="scripts/main.js"></script>
    <title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <?php 

            if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
                echo "<form action='includes/logout.php'>
                        <button>Log out</button>
                    </form>";
            else
                echo "<form action='includes/login.php' method='POST'>
                    <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username'>

                    <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'>
                    <button class='button-submit' type='submit'>Login</button>
                    </form>";
            ?>
            <li><a href="../views/signup/default.php">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my signup code:

```
<?php require '../../includes/header.php'; ?>

<div class"container">
    <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
        echo 'You are already logged in!';
    else
        echo "<form action='../../includes/signup.php' method='POST'>
                <label for='firstname'>First name:</label>
                <input type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='First name'><br>

                <label for='lastname'>Last name:</label>
                <input type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='Last name'><br>

                <label for='username'>Username:</label>
                <input type='text' name='username' placeholder='username'><br>

                <label for='lastname'>Desired Password:</label>
                <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'><br>
                <button type='submit'>Sign up</button>
            </form>";
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS paths are relative. So it is trying to pull `/include/css/stylesheet.css` etc. Open the developer console and see what the request it is making is, then you should be able to use the absolute path to get it to load.

Comment: Ah okay, I do see that I am getting a 404 error. I thought the include of my header file in my **signup** would work `<?php require '../../includes/header.php'; ?>`

Comment: That is where `header.php` is but not where `css/stylesheet.css` is. The `css/stylesheet.css` is loaded/requested client side.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you!